# MVP Winforms and TPL

Tags: winforms, task-parallel-library, mvp

My application is currently synchronous, using MVP. I want to introduce TPL to pull back a report from a database which takes a number of seconds to generate. I have investigated threads and background workers and feel that Tasks are the way to go.

Where do I create my tasks? in the presenter? or do I create a wrapper class for the tasks and use that in my presenter? do i use IOC to inject into my presenter?

I am thinking of unit testing too, how easy is it to test a method in the presenter which creates asyc calls?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Programmers StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I am asking for advice on the best place to put the tasks, i dont have a problem implementing i just need guidance on placement. Is the presenter the best place?